# Resizing and Moving Visual Studio 2010 Windows Using Only the Keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2010 is it possible to resize and move docked IDE windows using only the keyboard? If possible what is the keyboard shortcut?